24V power supply turns off when connected to PCB
I've developed a four-channel signal conditioning circuit and fabricated it onto a PCB. However, I'm encountering an issue: when I connect it to a 24V supply and attempt to power it on, the power supply shuts off. Can anyone help identify the possible causes of this problem? I'm attaching the schematic for a single channel for reference.


Short: Your power supply is shutting off because you're shorting it out
Longer:
It's proably because you're feeding your 79xx linear regulators backwards.
It seems you're trying to create two negative rails with the 79xx linear regulators. For them to do what you want you'll have to power them with a negative voltage. If you want to create a negative voltage from a positive you you need a switching regulator that chops up the input voltage and converts it to a negative voltage.

can you recommend some 1A switching regulators to convert positive to negative voltage

you can make a "regular" smps module into a negative one with a simple modification: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5eB_2wjLTg

I have the IC numbers MAX17577 and MAX17578, which are inverting DC-DC converters. Are these suitable to use in my design?

@priya You could solve your problem quickly if your supply voltage doesn't really have to be the full ±15V: your 24V supply can't be grounded on its negative output or at least not connected to the ground (0V point) of your circuit, and you should use ±9V instead, with LM7809 and LM7909. You might get away with ±10V at the most, but it's not guaranteed. I could draw or give you a simple voltage regulator supply in that case.

@priya In either case, the MAX17577/8 should work fine for you, but it might introduce high-frequency noise because it's a switching regulator and yours is a signal-conditioning circuit which might be sensitive to this.
